# What causes a form not to fire FormResize?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

In Delphi XE3 I have a form that gets an initial FormResize event and no more. If I resize the form by dragging a corner I get no FormResize event and any aligned controls do not move/resize. The form is BorderStyle: bsSizeable.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that exposes your problem?

Comment: This will happen when `OnResize` is `nil`, or perhaps is set to an event handler other than the one you intend.

Comment: I don't have a minimal example unfortunately. It is one of about 50 forms in a large project. It is the only one that seems to show the issue and is quite large itself.

Comment: Well, time to get to work and create an example. Otherwise this is a non-question. This might help: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan, I knew OnResize wasn't nil so I looked deeper into the VCL Dispatch mechanism ... and found I had message mapped WM_MOVE (to try and debug a previous oddity).

Comment: It seems unlikely that this will help anyone else. Do you really want to leave it here?

Comment: As a testament to my stupidity? Could it just disappear silently into the waves....

Comment: @Rob: You can delete your Q if you want to (you might need to delete your A first).

Answer (score 2):

Answer: when you override WM_MOVE and WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED which I had put into investigate something else (duh).  Moral: Fix one bug at a time.

Comment: Maybe you also forgot some `inherited`?

Comment: This could actually be a good question/answer combo, **IF** these details were exposed in the question. Without mentioning that you use `WM_MOVE` etc in your question, this all becomes meaningless to others. If you like, edit your question to include a small sample reproduction of the issue, and I would up-vote the question (answer already is).

Comment: What could I add to the question without also giving the asnwer